# Fortran DLL in Python wrapper, output for same function varies

Tags: python, dll, fortran, ctypes

I have adapted my code from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32132080/calling-a-fortran-dll-using-ctypes)

My ultimate goal is to:
- pack up some Fortran code in a DLL (already completed)
- create a Python wrapper as an interface to receive inputs from a source, and provide those inputs into a DLL and pass them into the DLLs Fortran function
- return the output of the function to pass on to another Python program.

So far, I've been using this example as a prototype (for what I will eventually adapt this to), an getting different outputs every time.

as shown here:

```
    C:\Users\NAME\Desktop>python.exe py_wrapper.py
    <CDLL 'fort_test', handle 6f800000 at 0x25e174ec2e8>
    <_FuncPtr object at 0x0000025E17617388>
    <_FuncPtr object at 0x0000025E17617388>
    c_long(3)
    390943376        <---int value (my annotation for clarity)
    <class 'int'>
    c_long(390943376)
    <__main__.LP_c_long object at 0x0000025E174D54C8>
```

and

```
    C:\Users\NAME\Desktop>python.exe py_wrapper.py
    <CDLL 'fort_test', handle 6f800000 at 0x23fa636c2e8>
    <_FuncPtr object at 0x0000023FA6497388>
    <_FuncPtr object at 0x0000023FA6497388>
    c_long(3)
    -1506454896       <---int value (my annotation for clarity)
    <class 'int'>
    c_long(-1506454896)
    <__main__.LP_c_long object at 0x0000023FA63554C8>
```

Here is the content of my Fortran code:

```
    subroutine ex(i)
    integer i
    i=i+1
    return i
    end
```

and here is my Python wrapper: (there's a lot of test stuff in here)

```
    from ctypes import *

    DLL = CDLL('fort_test')
    print(DLL)

    print(getattr(DLL, 'ex_'))
    print(DLL.ex_)

    x = pointer(c_int(3))
    print(x.contents)
    res = DLL.ex_(x)
    print(res)
    print(type(res))
    proc_res = pointer(c_int(res))
    print(proc_res.contents)
    print(proc_res)
```

My question is, does anyone know why this output keeps changing? My input was 3 in the code, I'd expect an output of four given the function, but I am getting what looks like memory addresses (see my annotations in the output examples) or a signed integer representation of a memory address?

Comment: Although it doesn't matter here, `return i` in the Fortran subroutine probably doesn't mean what you think it means.

Comment: Oh I forgot to take that out hah. I was fiddling with stuff, I don't really know fortran that well haha (hence why I am trying to wrap it, the piece of code I really want to do this to is much larger, and I cannot post it here)

Comment: I'm not familiar with Fortan calling convention, but you *are* passing a pointer to an integer and not the actual integer.  My guess is your are receiving the address and not the value.  Have you tried a simple `res = DLL.ex_(3)`?

Comment: @MarkTolonen I have tried this and it returns: WindowsError: exception: access violation reading 0x0000000000000003, so it's expecting an address but it's not returning a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:

I have solved my issue.

```
from ctypes import *

DLL = windll.fort_test
print DLL

x = byref(c_int(3)) 
print x res = DLL.ex_( x )
print cast(res,POINTER(c_int)).contents
```

I cleaned this up a lot as well.
I pass by reference still, then cast the memory address that is returned as a c_int pointer (all caps is important) and dereference it using the '.contents' function pointers have

Comment: Look up `argtypes` and `restype` to make calling easier.